# Unable to call jquery truncate plug-in a second time when expanding/collapsing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulty calling the jquery truncate plug-in a second time after I expand my div on `.toggle`.

I am able to initially call it to truncate my description, but then when I expand my div, i'd like to essentially show more description text (but not all of it). Then when collapsing the div, i'd like to call it yet again to set it back to the default truncated text.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4bA7X/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'truncate'

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery plugin instead: http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/. It works!